# Can I use PHP in conjunction with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I know you can't use PHP inside of Javascript. Basically what I'm trying to do Is after clicking a link on one side of the web page, information that was stored in  a database will appear on the other side. So I know I can use javascript to make my lists on one side clickable but I also know that to get the data I want displayed from my database I need to use PHP to get it. Is there a way to make this work?

EDIT:
Heres some of my current code
At what point could I implement PHP here after the user clicks on one of the lists?

```
<script>
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "My First JavaScript";

  function myFnc(x) {
    if (x == 'Tiger') {
      document.getElementById('imgDiv').innerHTML = 'Img1';
    } else if (x == 'Bull') {
      document.getElementById('imgDiv').innerHTML = 'Img3';
    }
  }

  function myFunc2(x) {
    if (x == 'Hammer') {
      document.getElementById('imgDiv').innerHTML = 'Img2';
    }
  }

</script>

<article>
  <ul style="list-style-type:none">
    <li><a href="#Tiger" onclick="myFnc('Tiger')">Tiger</a></li>
    <li><a href="#Hammerhead" onclick="myFunc2('Hammer')">Hammerhead</a></li>
    <li><a href="#Bull" onclick="myFnc('Bull')">Bull</a></li>
    <li><a href="#Great White">Great White</a></li>
    <li><a href="#Mako">Mako</a></li>
    <li><a href="#Greenland">Greenland</a></li>
    <li><a href="#Whale">Whale</a></li>
    <li><a href="#Thresher">Thresher</a></li>
    <li><a href="#Oceanic">Oceanic WhiteTip</a></li>
    <li><a href="#Goblin">Goblin</a></li>
  </ul>
</article>

<div class="hold">
  <div id="imgDiv"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: jQuery Ajax is your friend - http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: AJAX - because in your description, JS runs in the browser, and PHP on the server - bi-directional "communication" between the two usually requires the use of AJAX

Comment: Yes, write the php code on the other side of the page, that's what we all do

Comment: it's not about using one "inside" the other: PHP runs on the server, JS runs in the browser, so design your pages to work with that. If your page needs data, write JS that will run in the bwoser, to call a url that is served by a php script that yields that data.

Comment: @WebCode.ie - I'd agree ... except remove reference to jQuery, there is no need for jQuery unless you want to use jQuery

Comment: @JaromandaX nah, jquery is great

Comment: @JaromandaX ajax for this?

Comment: @surge10 - not 100% sure actually - reading the question it seems like the OP wants an AJAX solution, however, now that I've read the question again, a simple `<form>` seems to be adequate - not sure how your answer deals with `clicking` at all to be perfectly honest!!

Comment: @JaromandaX can you elaborate a little on that? Like how should the form be set up in relation to when the javascript is used to make the list clickable?

Comment: well yes, whether the click of a common link or a form submission, the query string can still be there in fact it is recommended, even the GET string is the least requirement

Comment: @ParPro - not really, as now I'm unsure as to your requirements ... if you need to know how to use `<form>` with PHP backend, however, there's about a bajillion tutorials on the *internet* that explains in detail how to achieve such majicks

Comment: Ajax in unnecessary, considering that it will still require php to run on a particular 'side'. If its not heavily needed, it should be avoided

Comment: @WebCode.ie Your last comment makes me think of [this gem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sGhaO.gif).

Comment: @Ivar - Not the joke I was referencing but similar - LOL!

Comment: @Ivar can't stop laughing... HaHaHaHa

Comment: Oh, I get it! I thought @WebCode.ie was being serious!!

Comment: @JaromandaX - the penny drops!

Comment: If you're just getting started with PHP and want to build applications, I'd also strongly recommend looking at various [development frameworks](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) to see if you can find one that fits your style and needs. They come in various flavors from lightweight like [Fat-Free Framework](https://fatfreeframework.com/) to far more comprehensive like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/). These give you concrete examples to work from and much stronger guidance on how to write your code and organize your files.

Answer (score 0):

Write like this

on the First side the link should be:

```
'other_side.php?show_table=true'
```

And on the other side the site should be something like this

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['show_table'])) {
// connect to database and do database query here
}
?>
<!Doctype html>
<html>
</html>
```

Comment: I would not insert an extra newline before doctype.

Comment: You can ignore or insert as many as you want dear, it won't matter

Comment: From memory, Internet Explorer is very picky about the `<!DOCTYPE>` declaration position

Comment: I didn't know that? Even when the php code is closed

Comment: The php may be closed, but you still have a newline after it, and that counts.

Comment: @surge10 I'd anyway prefer, for sake of precision, to do `?><!doctype html>`

Comment: @Cranio ok dear.

Answer (score 0):

1. First of all, imagine that you have the next database:

```php
| id | product |price|
|---|----------|-----|
| 1 |  Cheese  | 10  |
| 2 |  Milk    | 20  |
| 3 |  Candy   | 5   |
```

---

2. Second, you need the **get_data.php** file done but printing the
   data as JSON. Something like this:

```js
    [
      {id: 1, product: "Cheese", price: 10},
      {id: 2, product: "Milk",   price: 20},
      {id: 3, product: "Candy",  price: 5}
    ]
```

3. Third, once you have these done, use an AJAX call to retrieve the data from the **get_data.php**, you can find a lot of examples with Jquery and Vanilla JS.
4. Finally, just use a click event on the link.

Here you can find an example of every separated task:

- [Get data from database](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.query.php)
- Printing data as JSON, with:

```php
        <?php
            $data = /** The data from our table **/;
            header('Content-Type:application/json');       
            echo json_encode($data);
        ?>;
```

- [Jquery AJAX POST](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)
- [Event clicks](https://api.jquery.com/click/) | [Event Click with On](https://api.jquery.com/on/)
- [Parse Objects with Javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/JSON/parse)

Comment: For example, MDN has [fantastic documentation on `JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) and all things JavaScript. The [official PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) is likewise very good.